# Dart - set mimetype of HttpClientRequest

Tags: dart

Is there some way to set the `mimeType` of `HttpClientRequest` ?

I'm trying to do some unittests where I create an instance of `HttpClient` and then sent a post request with a bytes of data to a `HttpServer` and then parse it based on the `mimeType` I set. Something like this :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080)
    .then((HttpServer server) {
      server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
        String mimeType = request.headers.contentType.mimeType;
        if (mimeType == 'application/json') {
          // parse bytes of data to json and then to map
        } else if (mimeType == 'text/plain') {
          // parse bytes of data to string
        }
        // do something with data
        // close response
      });
    });
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.open('POST', '127.0.0.1', 8080, '/')
    .then((HttpClientRequest r) {
      r.add('{"val": 5}'.codeUnits);
      // already tried both
      r.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json'); // doesn't work
      r.headers.contentType = ContentType.parse('application/json'); // doesn't work
      r.close();
    });
}
```

So the `HttpHeaders` is immutable. Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpClientRequest.htmll#add), data should not be modified after an add() call. Setting the header before you add the data will work:

```dart
  r.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');
  r.add('{"val": 5}'.codeUnits);
```